# Add pattern overlay over drawn text with transparent background

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick to create transparent images from text with PHP.

I would like to know if it's possible (and how) to add a pattern overlay over the generated image.
The idea is to leave the background transparent and to apply the texture over the text :

The actual result:

[image: Actual result]

The desired result:

[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [ImagickDraw](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagickdraw.php) to create a "draw" object (it's like a layer), then add it over your image. Here's an example:

```
// create canvas
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setfont('/path/to/your/font.ttf');

// load your overlay image
$overlay = new Imagick('/path/to/your/pattern.png');

// define pattern
$draw->pushPattern('myOverlay', 0, 0,
   $overlay->getImageWidth(), $overlay->getImageHeight());

// fill canvas with the pattern (tile)
$draw->composite(Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPY, 0, 0,
   $overlay->getImageWidth(), $overlay->getImageHeight(), $overlay);

// destroy pattern
$draw->popPattern();   
$draw->setFillPatternURL('#myOverlay');

// put text
$draw->setFontSize(100);
$draw->annotation(0, 0, 'My TextImage');

// create your image (800x400)
$output = new Imagick();
$output->newimage(800, 400, 'transparent');

// this will center your canvas
$output->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER);

// render canvas on this image
$output->drawImage($draw);

$output->setImageFormat('png');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
print $output;
```

If you want the overlay to be stretched to fit 800x600, then use that size instead of the pattern size when compositing